# ubuntu set system proxy from command line

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, command-line-interface

Using server version of 10.4 beta 2

Need to to set the proxy that the system needs to use

Thanks

Comment: I would like to setup the proxy from a /etc/network/interfaces file, which has been enhanced with guessnet-magic; so depending on the network I end up using I want to setup the system wide proxy.

Comment: oh man, this is just mean, over 10k views, and only 4 up boats :(

Answer (score 13):

Depending on your needs you could add

```
   http_proxy="http://your.proxy.here:3128/"
   https_proxy="http://your.proxy.here:3128/"
   ftp_proxy="http://your.proxy.here:3128/"
```

to `/etc/environment` to have them set by the login-process.

cheerio

Comment: would this apply the proxy settings even if no one logs in? Ideally, I don't want to have to arse around on the machine, just to update it or what not.

Comment: Typo: `cat /etc/environment`

Comment: There is also AUTO_PROXY for URL to PAC file formats.

Comment: Once you've updated your `/etc/environment` file, you can make sure the changes take place immediately for the current session without having to log off and back on, by running `source /etc/environment`.

Answer (score 1):

To proxy updates, add a new file called `01proxy` to your /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ directory with the following line:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://[user]:[password]@[server_ip_or_name]:[port#]";
```

Substitute the user name/password used to log into the proxy (if required), the server ip or fully-resolved name, and the proxy port # to use when adding this line.

Answer (score 1):

@Lairsdragon is correct (set /etc/environment), but there are more nuances.

An application will typically need to be run with this environment in place, for instance, from a login shell.  That said, it's even more complex than that:

- Many applications, especially servers are smart enough to consult /etc/environment.
- Many don't consult /etc/enironment.
- Some applications don't support proxies at all.
- Others are configured with their own configuration files.
- Still others will read from a different global file (like the gconf registry).

To really set something, you need to read the documentation on a particular application you are interested in to make sure you have set the correct file.  Chances are, it will talk about how to set up a http_proxy somewhere in it's docs if it supports this.

This is similar on all operating systems.  Setting network proxies is a confusing mess with many different and varied approaches to solving this problem.

Some References:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 0):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/01/squid-proxt-server.html

in place of yum install you can use sudo apt-get install squid then follow the blog!!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.